# SSH Terminal with grid view

Tags: node.js, ssh, terminal, windows-shell

I've been in the IT sector for many years and used plenty of terminals but never found the ONE.
I'm looking something like the pic below, where I can surf on each server on the right side of the window.

https://ibb.co/mGEkx7 ""

Comment: How about [this](http://www.ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/)?

Comment: @BibekShah Thanks but MTPuTTY is not what I’m looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Manage it with screen (on unix):

[image]

Edit your screen.rc conf :

```
nano /etc/screenrc
```

Copy this lines at the end of the file :

```
autodetach on
startup_message off
hardstatus alwayslastline
shelltitle 'bash'

hardstatus string '%{gk}[%{wk}%?%-Lw%?%{=b kR}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{=b kR})%{= w}%?%+Lw%?%? %{g}][%{d}%l%{g}][ %{= w}%Y/%m/%d %0C:%s%a%{g} ]%{W}'
```

Create a screen, named ssh:

```
 screen -dmS ssh
```

Add a tab named sshPane1 in your screen with first ssh connexion:

```
 screen -S ssh -X screen -t sshTab1 ssh user@monip
```

Add a second tab named sshPane2 in your screen with second ssh connexion:

```
 screen -S ssh -X screen -t sshTab2 ssh user@monip2
```

Create a script to automatically do this.

Then you can see your screen with :

```
screen -ls
```

[image]

You can enter inside with, by specifying the number of the screen :

```
screen -r 9312
```

Or open the last created with :

```
screen -r
```

Now you have your screen :

[image]

You can quit it with: CTRL+A CTRL+D

You can change the tab with CTRL+A 1 to go to the first,
CTRL+A 2 to go to the second, ...

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but how about having list of servers on the right side and you can switch between ?

Comment: It something which look like, you can have the list of your server in bottom